# Serial Communication Not working in APM 2.8

Tags: quadcopters, flight-controller, electronics, ardupilot

I have being trying to establish *Serial Communication* connection between **APM 2.8** and **Raspberry Pi** Board. But the connection is not being recognized in the Raspberry Terminal Console. 
[image]
**Configuration Setup**:

*Model*: Quad-copter

*Type*: X

*Flight Controller*: APM 2.8 FC

*Companion Computer*: Raspberry Pi 3 Model B+

I have being digging through [web archives](https://web.archive.org/web/20150310022621/http://dev.ardupilot.com/wiki/companion-computers/raspberry-pi-via-mavlink/) and found only MAVProxy Connection with Pixhawk & Raspi. Any help, advice, or guidance would be helpful.

Current Refereed:[Here](https://www.ryugakujapan.com/blog/quadcopter-up-and-flying)

Answer (score 2):

There are a bunch of problems which need to be overcome when using the RPi GPIO serial port.

1. The RPi normally runs a login process on the serial port, this will need to be disabled.

```
sudo systemctl stop serial-getty@ttyS0.service
sudo systemctl disable serial-getty@ttyS0.service
```

you will also need to edit `/boot/cmdline.txt` and remove this part: `console=serial0,115200`

2. On a RPi 3/4 the port name in linux if different to the port name used on older RPi's.
3. If using a recent image, the serial port is disabled in the config.txt by default. To fix this you need to edit `/boot/config.txt` and add the following line.

```
enable_uart=1
```

This page [Configuring The GPIO Serial Port On Raspbian Jessie and Stretch Including Pi 3 and 4](https://spellfoundry.com/2016/05/29/configuring-gpio-serial-port-raspbian-jessie-including-pi-3-4/) has a very good writeup on how to get it all working.

Also make sure that you are connecting RX on the RPi to TX on the APM and vice-versa.

Comment: On recent images, there is the potentially easier option to use ```sudo raspo-config``` -> ```5 Interfacing Options``` -> ```P6 Serial``` -> "Would you like a login shell to be accessible over serial?" ```No``` then exit and reboot.